# What determines where the browser starts looking for pages?

Tags: apache, digital-ocean

Sorry if I used the wrong terminology, I'm really new to web development/server stuff outside of Wordpress. I just made a DigitalOcean server and followed a bunch of tutorials to get it setup. I got my LAMP stack setup, but I got to the point in the tutorial where I created a quick php page and added it into /var/www as info.php. But when I go to my server IP/info.php, it couldn't find the page. It was only able to find the page when I moved it inside of /var/www/html which also contained index.html. My question is, what makes the browser/server look inside of html for files instead of /var/www?

My best guess is some apache config file that I'm not familiar with but I really have no idea.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in your apache httpd.conf file, most likely in /etc/httpd/conf on your server, for this command:

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"